# How to learn more about statements such as 'not without = only with'? Is this logic?

Tags: logic, language

(For this [ELL question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/49065/8712)), I only realised my main problem after user 'Araucaria' identified  it:

> If we use **not without** in a sentence, it has the same meaning as **only with** or **only by**.

Yet I never knew this before! Are there any lists of such equivalences, where a negative can be rewritten as a positive? Which branch of philosophy covers this? Logic? Which kind?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be an English language issue and the philosophical problem is unclear.

Comment: @Keelan I'm asking if logic covers this? Then this involves philosophy?

Comment: I don't think "Does logic cover --- ?" is inherently on topic. Compare: on SO, a question "Can [programming language] do --- ?" is considered low quality. This is really just a language issue, even though it happens to be one with a philosophical context.

Comment: I'm a little mixed on this one as to whether we should close it. Translating normal sentences to logic is a common foundational problem in philosophy, but if the reason translation is failing is inadequate grasp of the language, that doesn't seem like a fit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simple logic.  The difficult steps are not the logic (maybe--I managed to mess it up in my first attempt at an answer!), but that English has many different ways to say the same thing, but whose different ways imply different things.

```
X not-without Y
```

means

```
not(X without Y)
```

which means

```
not(X and not Y)
```

which simplifies to

```
(not X) or Y
```

or in a truth-table:

```
     T F (X)
   -----
 T | T T
 F | F T    <--- that F there is the "X without Y" slot being ruled out
(Y)
```

This truth-table is better known as implication, `X => Y`.

"Only with" means that you can only have `X` if you also have `Y`.  The only clear counterexample would be `X == true, Y == false`, and that gives the same truth table.  So that's *also* `X => Y`.

We could also use "implies"--same truth table again.

The sneaky part with English is that when you use "not without" you are *also* implying that `X` is likely or assumed or proposed, and that `Y` is in real danger of being left out and the speaker really doesn't want it to be left out.  This doesn't fall under logic, but this sort of thing *does* fall under the philosophy of language (specifically, how to account for "implicature", i.e. these sort of subtle conveyances of meaning).

(In contrast "only with" makes it sound like there is less of a danger that `Y` will be left out, and more of a danger that `X` will fail because someone forgot that `Y` was a prerequisite.  "Implies" makes it sound like `X` comes first but that there is no way to avoid `Y` once you've got `X`.  In many cases, the implicature of "not without" and "only with" is close enough so that either phrasing is fine; typically they would not be interchangeable with "implies", however.)

Comment: +1. Thanks. 1. Can you apply DeMorgan's Law to simplify: `not(X and not Y)` = not X or Y? 2. But then, if you apply http://math.stackexchange.com/q/475776, the answer is X => Y? NOT X <= Y, as you wrote? 2. When you wrote `that gives the same truth table`, you just meant one entry in the truth table above? Why would you need to redo the truth table?

Comment: Will you please to respond in your answer, which is easier to read than comments?

Comment: @LawArea51Proposal-Commit - Yes, of course, it's regular implication.  Sorry!  I'd switched the names on myself.